# origin/HEAD　ブランチについて

Tags: git

ローカルリポジトリ（Ａ）からのスタートで、リモートリポジトリにＰＵＳＨした時、
そのローカルリポジトリ（Ａ）には、「origin/HEAD」ブランチはありません。
但し、上記リモートリポジトリからcloneしたローカルリポジトリ（Ｂ）には、「origin/HEAD」ブランチはありました。

質問です。

1. origin/HEADは、リモートリポジトリのデフォルトブランチを指すらしいのですが、必要なのでしょうか？
2. 必要な場合、何に使用されるものなのでしょうか？
3. ローカルリポジトリ（Ａ）で、 git remote set-head origin -a で、origin/HEADを作成できるらしいのですが、「origin/HEAD ->remote/origin/master」となってしまいます。ローカルリポジトリ（Ｂ）では、「origin/HEAD ->origin/master」となっていますが、これらは意味が異なるのでしょうか？

Comment: 1,2の質問への回答には十分なものでした。ありがとうございます。ただ、3への質問に関してはどう考えるべきでしょうか。また、なぜローカルスタートの場合は、「origin/HEAD」は無いのでしょうか。

Comment: ローカルのリポジトリ(A),(B)でそれぞれ ’git branch -a’ の実行結果を質問内容に追記してみてください。また、リモートリポジトリは具体的にどのサービス(github, gitlab, bitbacket, その他)を利用されていますか？